# When the application server requires a restart, for which file type changes?

Tags: java, weblogic11g, jakarta-ee

I am using Weblogic Application server currently, i would like to know the type of files which definitely requires a restart to function as desired.

As part of enterprise application usage, i know for js and jsp it does not require restart. What else can be, please help me in knowing. Thanks.

Comment: You mean a redeployment not a restart, imho?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All files flagged as resources: images, not dinamic web pages, CSS, javascripts, *.xsd etc.

All other files used by your enterprise application need a weblogic restart.

For example: you have some *.properties files read during the startup of the server to create a singleton. Those files, read ONLY during the startup, need a full weblogic restart in order to be refreshed by your E.Application.

Generally, all files read at the startup and maintained in the server memory, need a full restart of the server.